# How do I "not" select first character in a regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I am a RegEx beginner and trying to identify the endings of different statements in sms. See screenshot below.

How can I avoid selecting the next letter following by a full-stop that indicates ending of a statement.

Note that some statements have `<.><Alphabets>` while some have `<.><space><Alphabets>`

Regex used: `r"\. ?[\D]"`

Sample SMS: - I want to select just the full-stop and space if any.

```
Txn of USD 00.00 done using TC XX at POS*MERCH on 30-Feb-22. Avl bal:USD 00.00. Call xxxxxx for dispute or SMS BLOCK xxxx to xxxxxxx

Acct XX debited with USD XX.00 on some date.Info: ABC*BDECS-XYZ.Avbl Bal:USD yy,xxx.95.Call xxxxxx for dispute or SMS BLOCK xx to xxxxx
```

[screenshot from RegExr on regular pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5N6i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a *look-ahead* group. Whether you make that a positive look-ahead and use the negated character set `\D` or a negative look-ahead with the character set `\d` doesn't really matter- I'll outline both below:

```py
regex = r". ?(?=\D)"  # asserts that the following character matches \D
regex = r". ?(?!\d)"  # asserts the following character does NOT match \d
```

There's also look-behind variants `(?<!pattern)` and `(?<=pattern)`, which assert that the pattern doesn't/does match just before the current position.

None of these groups capture the matched text- they just "look ahead" or "look behind" without changing state.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\. ?[\D]` is matching a single non digit char, but also that non digit char can be space or a newline by itself.

If you want to match a dot only, but not when it is the last character in the string, you can assert optional spaces without newlines.

Then match a non whitespace char not being a digit.

```
\.(?=[^\S\n]*[^\s\d])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is directly to the right of the current position is

  - `[^\S\n]*` Match optional whitespace chars without a newline
  - `[^\s\d]` Match a single non whitespace char other than a digit
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SL727W/1).